# socket.emit() vs. socket.send()

Tags: sockets, node.js, socket.io

What's the difference between these two?

I noticed that if I changed from `socket.emit` to `socket.send` in a working program, the server failed to receive the message, although I don't understand why.

I also noticed that in my program if I changed from `socket.emit` to `socket.send`, the server receives a message, but it seems to receive it multiple times. When I use `console.log()` to see what the server received, it shows something different from when I use `socket.emit`.

Why this behavior? How do you know when to use `socket.emit` or `socket.send`?

Comment: Also be aware, future readers of this post, that this is about `socket.io`, not node.js TCP, UDP or Unix sockets.

Answer (score 150):

With `socket.emit` you can register custom event like this:

server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

The `socket.send` function does the same, but you don't register to your custom 'news' event name, but to the `message` event:

server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.send('hi');
});
```

client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('message', function (message) {
  console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like a very big difference. It sees like socket.emit() can do everything that socket.on() can. Why did they have to make that function?

Comment: I don't know, I checked the source code and they make almost the same (https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L318). Maybe it's historical and just for backwards compatibility.

Comment: socket.io's making emit() do something other than what EventEmitter's emit() does is baffling, isn't it? It's a protocol on top of the raw pseudosockets that come out as named events on the far side, rather than raw messages. It lets you use a single socket for multiple streams, in a sense, multiplexing them.

Comment: Also be aware, future readers of this post, that this is about socket.io, not node.js TCP, UDP or Unix sockets.

Comment: Is it possible to emit with vanilla javascript Websockets?

Comment: Looks like `socket.send` is simply just an alias for `socket.emit('message', message);`

Answer (score 124):

Simple and precise (Source: [Socket.IO google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/socket_io/2UvtNHpd-W4)):

`socket.emit` allows you to emit custom events on the server and client

`socket.send` sends messages which are received with the `'message'` event

Answer (score 50):

TL;DR:

`socket.send(data, callback)` is essentially equivalent to calling `socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(data), callback)`

Without looking at the source code, I would assume that the send function is more efficient *edit: for sending string messages, at least*?

So yeah basically emit allows you to send objects, which is very handy.

Take this example with `socket.emit`:

```
sendMessage: function(type, message) {
    socket.emit('message', {
        type: type,
        message: message
    });
}
```

and for those keeping score at home, here is what it looks like using `socket.send`:

```
sendMessage: function(type, message) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: type,
        message: message
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 28):

`socket.send` is implemented for compatibility with vanilla WebSocket interface. `socket.emit` is feature of Socket.IO only. They both do the same, but `socket.emit` is a bit more convenient in handling messages.

Comment: socket.emit is not limited to Socket.IO but works on net too.

Comment: It's not only limited to Socket.io. Check out ws: https://github.com/websockets/ws#sending-and-receiving-text-data

Answer (score 0):

In basic two way communication systems, socket.emit has proved to be more convincing and easy to use (personal experience) and is a part of Socket.IO which is primarily built for such purposes

Answer (score 0):

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-send-args-ack

`socket.send` // Sends a message event

`socket.emit(eventName[, ...args][, ack])` // you can custom eventName

Answer (score 0):

### update v4.x

According to the official docs:

[`socket.send`](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketsendargs) - sends a `message` event. This can used like this:

```
// Client side
socket.send('hello')

// Server side
socket.on('message', (data) => {
   console.log(data) // hello
})
```

[`socket.emit`](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args) - send a **custom** event. This is used like this:

```
// Client side
socket.emit('hello', 'rick')

// Server side
socket.on('hello', (name) => {
   console.log(name) // rick
})
```

**I would personally recommend using socket.emit, as it's more simpler to understand, and keeps things consistent**