# How can I send a message from a flask route to a socket using flask-socketio

Tags: python, flask, bitcoin, flask-socketio

I have the following scenario I would like to implement:

- User surfs to our website
- User enters a bitcoin address.
- A websocket is created to the server, passing the address.
- The server registers a [callback with Blocktrail](https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs#webhooks_init)
- When the callback is triggered (a payment was seen by Blocktrail) we send a message back to the browser.
- The page the user is browsing is updated to show the message recieved

I'm using [webhooks from the Blocktrail API](https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs#webhooks_init) to "listen" to an event, being the reception of coins on an address.

Now, when the event happens, the API does a POST to my URL. This should send a message to the browser that is connected to my server with socket.io (such as 'payment seen on blockchain')

So the question is,

How can I send a message from a route to a socket using flask-socketio

Pseudo code:

```
@app.route('/callback/<address>')
def callback(id):
    socketio.send('payment seen on blockchain')

@socketio.on('address',address)
def socketlisten(address):
    registerCallback(address)
```

Comment: Could you please describe a litte bit more clear how, what, in which order something should happen. May also look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498508/socket-emit-vs-socket-send for examples.

Comment: It is quite a difficult problem to explain but I will try to edit my question te elaborate more. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to describe how to solve this using Flask-SocketIO beta version 1.0b1. You can also do this with the 0.6 release, but it is a bit more complicated, the 1.0 release makes addressing individual clients easier.

Each client of a socket connection gets assigned a session id that uniquely identifies it, the so called `sid`. Within a socket function handler, you can access it as `request.sid`. Also, upon connection, each client is assigned to a private room, named with the session id.

I assume the metadata that you receive with the callback allows you to identify the user. What you need is to obtain the `sid` of that user. Once you have it, you can send your alert to the corresponding room.

Example (with some hand-waving regarding how you attach a `sid` to an address):

```
@app.route('/callback/<address>')
def callback(address):
    sid = get_sid_from_address(address)
    socketio.send('payment seen on blockchain', room=sid)

@socketio.on('address')
def socketlisten(address):
    associate_address_with_sid(address, request.sid)
```

Comment: As promised I've tried this solution. I THINK it will work. Only trouble is I run the flask app with mod_wsgi on apache. I don't want to do socketio.run(app) with reverse proxy because I hate "manually" started processes on a production server. So I'm stuck on deployment to our testserver for now. Because other sites are running on this server as apache virtual hosts, I cannot just  switch to other webserver software either. So maybe it's time for this app's dedicated server...

Comment: @DennisDecoene if you use Apache/mod_wsgi you have bigger problems than `socketio.run()`. My understanding is that mod_wsgi does not play along well with coroutine frameworks, I think you will not be able to use eventlet or gevent if you deploy that way. I'm also unclear on what support mod_wsgi has for WebSocket, I believe it does not support it.

Comment: Well, I am testing now with a standalone 'socket.run()' and i upgraded to 1.0b4 on the server and 0.9.16 on the client but I'm giving up because I now get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClose' of null' on the client. this is the client connect: var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port, {resource:'socket.io'});

Comment: You need to use 1.3.x on the client. See the [documentation](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/v1.0/docs/index.rst#upgrading-to-flask-socketio-1x-from-older-releases).

Comment: Oh, of course, since I left the whole wsgi thing, I don't need 0.9.16 no more!!! [takes pistol, aims at brain, fires :D]