# Socket.io 'message' event fires, but individual listeners don't fire. Listeners registered in iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a main page, with an iframe in it.
The main page connects to my Node.JS server using socket.io.
The socket is stored in `window.socket`.
Then, in the iframe, I access the socket with `parent.window.socket`.
Running `console.log(parent.window.socket)` within the iframe shows that it is valid.

From within the iframe, I have a few things.
First, handlers are registered, for event `A`.
It has a clear output (console.log), so its not that the output code is bad.
I also have `socket.on('message')` to catch all messages.
Finally, I have some emits to send messages to the server.

I have confirmed that the server is connecting and receiving the messages, because the events from my emits and the connect/disconnect events fire.
However, when the server sends back a message in response, the event **doesn't fire**.
In `socket.on('message')`, I receive the message fine, with the proper data and arguments, but my event, `socket.on('A')`, doesn't fire.

I have checked:

- I am using the right WebSocket object in the iframe code.
- The iframe and 'viewer' page are server from the same domain and server (not a cross-origin issue)
- Messages are received on both ends but server isn't having the custom handler fired.
- No errors in console.
- Have tried using firefox debugger to step through code, and the variables and data sent is all correct.

EDIT: Also tested it in parent page - same behavior. It receives the message in `socket.on('message')`, but `socket.on('A')` is not fired.

Comment: does `socket.on('A')` work in the parent page?

Comment: @JohnLee tested it in parent page - same behavior. It receives the message in socket.on('message'), but in `socket.on('A')` it is not fired.

Comment: any sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Was using a mix of socket.send() and socket.emit() on client and server, but, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498508/socket-emit-vs-socket-send), send only fires the 'message' event and 'emit' fires the custom event. Using iframes had nothing to do with it.