# ReferenceError: socket is not defined. socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This error comes up in socket.io

//SERVER.JS

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port       = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var http       = require('http').Server(app);
var io         = require('socket.io')(http);
require('./app/routes.js')(app, io);
```

//ROUTES.JS

```
socket.emit('dlReady', { description: 'Your file is ready!'});
```

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: socket is not defined
```

EDIT:

```
app.post('/pst', function(req, res) {
        var url = req.body.convo;

        res.render('processing.ejs');

               funker(url).then(result => {
                    console.log('TAKE A LOOK AT THIS!'); 

                    socket.emit('dlReady', { description: 'Your file is ready!'});


                    //transforming array to string to pass to Buffer.from()
                    //then we remove ',' with newlines, so each index of array is a new line
                    var str = result.toString();
                    result = str.split(',').join('\r\n');
                    str = ''; //garbage collection
                    resultGlobal = result;
                    result = ''; //garbage collection




                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.render('error.ejs');
                })
    });
```

Comment: Please check how to use socket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498508/socket-emit-vs-socket-send

Comment: Show us the rest of the relevant code in routes.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to Use socket:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: In what file do i write the var io = require line?

Comment: And what happens when i want to emit an event, but not at the moment when a user connects?

Comment: Try this  io.sockets.emit('hello');

Comment: But this is what i did in the code i included in the question! What was the error in my code? The require line? Where do i write that?