# Socket.io: Socket.emit inside an event listener is working pretty weird

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

the problem in a nutshell is:
`socket.emit('test2')` inside `socket.on('test1')` is not working if the event 'test1' is fired with 
`socket.on('test1')` inside an event listener function in the browser.

process is supposed to go this way:

1. user clicks on the submit button on the webpage
2. event listener attached to the submit button executes `socket.emit('test1')`
3. `socket.on('test1')` function runs inside server
4. `socket.on('test1')` function includes `socket.emit('test2')` which is then fired
5. `socket.on('test2')` runs on the browser

problem is 5th step is not working, that means socket.emit('test2') didn't run in the 4th step.

can anyone tell me if i'm missing something here? 
why wouldn't it work? step 5 would work if `socket.on('test1') is not inside an event listener function.

EDIT: I've checked the browser websocket logs as suggested by @laggingreflex
and I've noticed the the 'test2' is fired by the server and *is* received
by the browser but the `socket.on('test2')` function is not invoked somehow, this is so strange.

heres the code piece if needed:

```
// SERVER SIDE

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var socket  = require('socket.io');

// console.log(process.env.PORT);
var ip = process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1';
var port = process.env.PORT || '1336';


var server = app.listen(port, ip);

io = socket.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected'+socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('REQlogin', function(data){
        socket.emit('test2',"this line won't work");
        console.log(data.username+" "+data.password);
    });


    socket.on('returnreqtest', function(){
        socket.emit('test',"this will work");
    });

//404 page

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404).send("not found");
});
```

```
// BROWSER SIDE

var socket = io()
// socket.emit('test', "testy");

var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginform');
var loginForm_Username = document.getElementById('loginform_username');
var loginForm_Password = document.getElementById('loginform_password');
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    login_data = {username: loginForm_Username.value,
                  password: loginForm_Password.value};
    socket.emit('REQlogin', login_data);
});

socket.on('test', function(da){
    da = da?da:"";
    console.log("."+da);
});

socket.on('test2', function(da){
    da = da?da:"";
    console.log("."+da);
});

// socket.emit('REQlogin', {username: "myassesess", password: "frickthis"}); //debug test
```

```
<!-- BROWSER HTML -->

<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/assets/styles/mainstyleA.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="preload flexColumn">
        <div id="mainwrapper" class="flexColumn">
            <form id="loginform" class="flexColumn">
                <p class="maintext">login</p>
                <span style="height:60px;"></span>
                <input id="loginform_username" class="log_reg_input"type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                <input id="loginform_password" class="log_reg_input"type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                <a href="register">create an account</a>
                <input id = "formsubmit" style="visibility: hidden;" type="submit"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src = "/assets/scripts/loginpagecode.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
/* CSS if you dont want to tackle an ugly page */
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* color: white */
}

.preload * {
    transition: none;
}

body{
    background-color: #7FFED4;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* +flex */
}

.flexColumn{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#mainwrapper{
    height:400px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    box-shadow: #7FFED4 2px 2px, white 5px 5px;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;

}

#mainwrapper:hover{
    box-shadow: #7FFED4 2px 2px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 30px 30px 30px;
}

.maintext{
    color: #5014c7;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
}

.log_reg_input{
    border: 2px solid rgb(7, 161, 167);
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 10px;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: letter-spacing .2s;
}

.log_reg_input:hover{
    letter-spacing: 2px;

}


.log_reg_input::placeholder{
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: letter-spacing .2s, color .2s;
}

.log_reg_input:focus{
    outline: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.log_reg_input:hover::placeholder{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    letter-spacing: 6px;
}

.log_reg_input:focus::placeholder{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0)
}

a:link, a:active, a:visited{
    text-decoration-line: none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

I'm a beginnner programmer, I hope I've simplified everything good enough.
Please ignore the semicolon and bracket errors if you notice any, I pasted and edited the code here.
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498508/socket-emit-vs-socket-send this will please you

Comment: @NarendraChouhan i want to be able to send custom events, and no that didnt work either, socket.send doesn't work too.

Comment: Is the "submit" eventHandler itself working as expected? And have you tried sending simple events (without data)? Try [enabling debug logs for socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/) (both on server and in browser) and see if anything brings out the issue (post the logs here if you like). Or look at [browser's native debug logging for websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome) (in case packets aren't making it to the server or back due to network related reasons)

Comment: @laggingreflex the "submit" event handle is working all fine, except that socket.emit in there is not working properly. As for the debug logs, i never used them and i'll try to use them.

Comment: @laggingreflex, alright, i've just checked the browser websocket logs, I noticed that 'test2' is fired by the server in response to 'test1' but 'test2' handler function on the browser is not getting invoked.