# what does socket.emit() do?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

```
socket.on("send_message", async (data) => {
  console.log("send_message", data);
  io.emit("send_message_receiver", data);
});
```

what does this function do?

Does `emit()` send a message to all the connected clients or only to the specific client?

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args | https://socket.io/docs/v3/emitting-events/ | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498508/socket-emit-vs-socket-send